# In java, why is it slow?

Tags: java, performance

I have defined a class with information:

```
    public static class Node {
        Node prev;
        public Node() {
        }
        public Node(Node prev) {
            this.prev = prev;
        }
    }
```

**Test case 1 :**

```
   @Test
    public void test1() {
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            Node newNode = new Node();
        }

        long timeRun = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("nanoTime: " + timeRun);
    }
```

For the above test case, my machine complete needs nanoseconds `8434100` -> 0.008 second

**Test case 2 :**

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Node last = null;
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            Node newNode = new Node();
            last = newNode ;
        }

        long timeRun = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("nanoTime: " + timeRun);
    }
```

In the above case, I will create a storage variable `last` to store the last `node` object.

For the above test case, my machine complete needs nanoseconds `9522600` -> 0.009 second

**Test case 3 :**

Mutation in this case.

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Node last = null;
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            Node newNode = new Node(last);
            last = newNode ;
        }

        long timeRun = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("nanoTime: " + timeRun);
    }
```

Case 3, quite similar to case 2 but I will pass `last` object to `constructor` of `Node`.
For the above test case, my machine complete needs nanoseconds `933890100` -> 0.9 second.

Amazingly, it's 100 times slower.

**Test case 4 :**

```
   @Test
    public void test() {
        List<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Node last = null;
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            Node newNode  = new Node(last);
            list.add(newNode);
            last = newNode ;
        }
        long timeRun = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("nanoTime: " + timeRun);
    }
```

In case 4, I had a `list` to store `newNode` to list.
For the above test case, my machine complete needs nanoseconds `360559900` -> 0.3 second.
It is faster than case 3. Did java re-optimize it?

**Questions**

Do you know why it's slow? please let me know. I have researched and read a lot but no answer yet

Comment: Micro benchmarks are misleading. The first two snippets are likely optimized away, the last one likely isn't because object references are kept.

Comment: [**How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. As [Dave Newton said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70225977/in-java-why-is-it-slow/70226014#comment124140321_70225977), microbenchmarks are misleading. More in this question's answers: [*How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)
2. But also probably: Because in cases 1 and 2, you don't build up ten million `Node` objects in memory, you have at most two at any given time. As you're going along, you release previous nodes. But in case 3, you keep all the `Node` objects you ever create, so you end up with ten million small objects in memory. That requires a lot of overhead in terms of memory management, slowing things down markedly.

Comment: @ThànhLê - *"As far as I know, when I create a new object in java, it lives in the heap."* Not necessarily, after optimization. Objects that are never retained in memory after the method they were created in returns can be created on the stack if the JVM optimizes the method. But yes, usually. *"Was it still in there before it was cleaned up."* I don't know what you mean by that...?

Comment: Can you help me see case 4 or not? It is faster than case 3

Comment: @ThànhLê - See #1 above. There's no point doing these naive microbenchmarks, they just waste your time. Use a proper benchmarking suite or (better) benchmark your actual code, where whatever this is is unlikely to be the bottleneck.

Comment: @ThànhLê - FYI, if you even just put `test` in a loop (say, 100 iterations), case 4 is reliably slower than case 3 on average (at least in the environment where I tried it). Case 3's times are dramatically varied, but the first run is reliably slow. Case 4's times are less varied and longer on average. Which takes us back to #1 above. :-) (Because even my version with a loop is still too naive to trust.)